# Set a variable value before the result of the rendered document

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

**I think that's impossible**, but just to ask, is there any way in classic ASP to set a variable value after calling it?
An example to be more clear:

```
<img src="<%=imgSrc%>" alt="An image" />
<% imgSrc="animage.jpg" %>
```

or another one but just to explain:

```
<img src="<%=imgSrc%>" alt="An image" />
<% ASP BEFORE RENDER
   imgSrc="animage.jpg"
%>
```

*Any tips will be good ;)*

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart I'm using a sub, but I would like to know if exist a method to prevent the document rendering.

Comment: A `Sub` isn't a good fit because nothing get's returned to the line being processed, whereas if you used a `Function` and returned the `imgSrc` string that would work. Ideally though need to see a more complete example of what you are doing to advise further.

Comment: You can use `Response.Flush` and `Response.Clear` to flush the buffer and send the content to the browser or empty the buffer and never send it but this won't help you bypass the linear way in which the ASP processor works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP engine processes the ASP file in a linear fashion.

In the example above the

```
<img src="<%=imgSrc%>" alt="An Image" />`
```

has already been written to the buffer, so anything that comes afterwards will not effect the outcome of that line.

The only exception is Sub Procedure *(although values defined in a Sub Procedure are not necessarily returned to the line being processed)* and Function calls that can be defined anywhere (top bottom etc) and their content will be processed before the line is written to the buffer so something like

```
<img src="<%= GetImage(...) %>" alt="An Image" />`
```

would work.

To expand on this you should be using a `Function` to gurantee the value is included on the line being processed a `Sub` cannot do this because it doesn't return anything *(technically you can return values from a `Sub` using `ByRef` but even that will not work for this scenario, because the `Sub` has to be called first before the `ByRef` value can be accessed)*.

Using the `GetImage()` example above

```vb
'This function in this form isn't useful at all but it
'demonstrates the technique.
Function GetImage()
  Dim imgSrc : imgSrc = "animage.jpg"
  GetImage = imgSrc
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is any way to do that. Nevertheless, it is a very bad practice. You should always declare you variables on the top and give values to them before you use.

Comment: I think that too, that's why I said that's just to ask.. Anyway we should think positive, the world is full of great and different ideas ;)